# Delete duplicate entries in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What is the command for deleting duplicate elements in an array? This is my best try:

```
my_array.reject.with_string{s.clone}
```

Comment: Try with "uniq" https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want an array of unique values of `my_array = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4]`, then do this:

```
my_array.uniq
# => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If your array contains objects with some field that you want to be unique, for example, `:fname` in:

```
my_array = [
  {fname: "amanze", age: 28}, 
  {fname: "ben", age: 13}, 
  {fname: "ben", age: 4}
]
```

then you need to do this:

```
my_array.uniq { |obj| obj[:fname] }
# =>
# [
#   {fname: "amanze", age: 28}, 
#   {fname: "ben", age: 13}
# ]
```

Comment: note your second example is invalid as `name` would raise an `NoMethodError` since `Hash#name` is not the appropriate way to access the key `name`

Comment: Oh! that's true. I've changed `name` to `fname`

Comment: Not exactly my point. If you run your code you will note the `NoMethodError` because `obj.name` should be `obj[:name]` or I guess, `obj[:fame]` now, because `obj` is a `Hash` and that class does not define `name` or `fname` as an instance method.

Comment: @engineersmnky Got you. Too much JS in my system.

Answer (score 3):

[`Array#uniq`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/uniq) is the best way to find out the uniq records, but as an alternate, you can use [`Array#&`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-26), which returns a new array containing the elements common to the two arrays, excluding any **duplicates**.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 3, 4]
b = a & a
b #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```